# Solaris 11 (GNOME) - Where is the "master" menu?

Tags: gnome, solaris

Something strange/catastrophic happened to my Solaris 11 installation, it uses GNOME. I need to know where the "master"-menu (the "Start-menu" listing programs and categories) is located.  I hope that'll be the first step to fix my problem...  So where is the menu defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu configuration can be found in

```
/etc/xdg/menu/
```

A more detailed description is [the Gnome Desktop Menu Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/menu-spec/). The application list is generated from the `.desktop` files in the directories

```
/usr/share/applications/
$HOME/.local/share/applications/
… and more
```

The `.desktop` files contain a *Categories* key, for instance:

```
Caterories=GNOME;System;Filesystem;
```

This is used to generate sensible categories in the menu. See also [freedesktop - Desktop Menu Specification.](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html)